# Using SQL Server for practise on Cloud

Tags: sql-server

Is anyone offering SQL Server for free on cloud for learning purposes? I need it for running simple queries that we come across while learning SQL concepts online. If available I can run the queries in my mobile or tab

Comment: Why not use SQL Express? Not 100% featured, but great for practice or simple dev scenarios. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

*If you are looking for online sql* , I would like to suggest you

- http://sqlfiddle.com for practice purpose.It support MySQL, Oracle, MS SqlServer, Postgre, SQLlite (create your account and save your work)
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp is another great option to
  run queries while learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Another +1 to w3schools. They have various demo databases that you can both query AS WELL AS modify. You can restore the original database with the click of a button which is great if you are learning. I have put a screenshot of an example that I just did so you can see what it looks like.

Also, because this is web based and all of the queries are handled on the server side, you can use this from any device with internet access, including iPad/Phone whatever.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cxUp.png

SQLFiddle is another great option, especially because you can select specifically which language you are using (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, etc) but it is a bit more advanced if you are just starting out because you will have to create a database/schema and insert data instead of simply manipulating existing data like you can with w3schools.